# SLiRP Error: Invalid Option

Tags: linux, usb, ppp, slirp

I'm trying to run SLiRP in my linux box but after executing this command:

```
 slirp -P -d -4 debugppp "ttyACM1" "dns 176.66.0.1" "dns 176.66.0.12 " "-vj" "mru 576" "mtu 576"
```

it shows:

```
Error: Invalid option: ttyACM1
```

I'm sure that the device is connected to port **ttyACM1** because when I run the **dmesg** command, it shows the following details:

```
[ 2872.180000] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=11ca, idProduct=0241
[ 2872.180000] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2872.180000] usb 1-1: Product: Trident USB Device 1.1
[ 2872.180000] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ***** Inc
[ 2872.210000] usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 2872.220000] cdc_acm 1-1:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the error appears because I'm passing the wrong parameter to SLiRP. The correct command line should be:

```
 slirp -P -d -4 debugppp "tty /dev/ttyACM1" "dns 176.66.0.1" "dns 176.66.0.12 " "-vj" "mru 576" "mtu 576"
```